# Geolocation watchPosition updating slowly

Tags: geolocation

Is it normal for the onSuccess routine from `geolocation.watchPosition` to update every second, even when the `maximumAge` is set to 0?

I detect this as followed:
The onSuccess value from `compass.watchHeading` is updating every 0,1 sec and showing in a div. When calling this value with `document.getElementById` in the onSuccess routine from `geolocation.watchPosition` and displaying it in a div nearby I see the value slowly updating, seems every second or so.

I need to use the heading value within the results of location, that's why I noticed.

To make it visible:

```
function onSuccess1(heading) {

    direction = Math.round(heading.magneticHeading);    
    // Debug info        
    document.getElementById('heading').innerHTML = direction;

}

function onSuccess2(position) {

    positionLat = position.coords.latitude;
    positionLong = position.coords.longitude;

    var direction = document.getElementById('heading').innerHTML;
    // Debug info
    document.getElementById('headingControle').innerHTML = direction;

}

<div id = "debug">
    <span id = "heading"></span><span id = "headingControle"></span>
</div>
```